# How to make individual item in CheckedlistBox read only

Tags: c#-2.0

I have checkedlistbox which is populated by month. I want to make alternate month in ChekedListbox as read only

Comment: You could handle the 'OnCheck' event, but I dont think you can disable an item.  Why not use a DataGridView instead? (That can do it)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I did not use Loop, but sure you can use one to add items.

```
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("January", "1", false));//its disabled
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Febuary", "1", true)); //its Enabled
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("March", "1", false)); //its disabled
```

I hope it helps,

Regards,

Mazhar Karimi

P.S. Happy Coding!!

Comment: I guess, you were binding the whole collection of "Month names" with your CheckBoxList, in that case, i'm suggesting a little bit different approach here, you can manually add items.